# Call Struts 2 action from javascript synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2, synchronous

I am trying to call a Struts 2 action with JavaScript synchronous. I found several examples but none of them had been worked.

The only thing I've got work is to call the action asynchronous like this:

```
function toggel(id) {
    var url = "./ToggelProcess.action";
    $.post(url, {id : id}, function (resp) {
        // resp is the response from the server after the post request.
    });
}
```

need an example like this that work.

Comment: Why do you think you want it to be synchronous? Not only is it a bad approach in most cases, but that behavior is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you should never actually intend to send synchronous requests, as they prevent your JS from doing further tasks while waiting, as JS is single-threaded. Your intention of sending synchronous request makes it really probable that your intention is a result of the lack of understanding asynchronous requests or the result of bad design. Instead of `$.post` I humbly suggest `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: {id : id},
  success: function (resp) {
        // resp is the response from the server after the post request.
  },
  async:false
});
```

But instead of that I suggest that you should rethink your code, write separate functions for what you intend to run when the response arrives and gall those functions in the callback.

Comment: ok, that is exactly what i looked for... so do i understand it correct that asynchronous is just set of for this post request ?

Comment: @John, that is the exact case, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this line inside your function, it will make the call synchronous one

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
```

Like this

```
function toggel(id) {
 $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    var url = "./ToggelProcess.action";
    $.post(url, {id : id}, function (resp) {
        // resp is the response from the server after the post request.
    });
}
```

Comment: I do not like this solution. You are modifying the default value of async to a deprecated one. If one wants to send a given request synchronously, then fine, he/she will be doing that and later refactor the code. But to make it the default setting... Well, I do not agree.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a synchronous calls, it's highly discouraged because it makes the browser unresponsive. Some browsers like Firefox made the synchronous API deprecated.

> Note: Starting with Gecko 30.0 (Firefox 30.0 / Thunderbird 30.0 / SeaMonkey 2.27), synchronous requests on the main thread have been deprecated due to the negative effects to the user experience.
>
> In rare cases, the use of a synchronous method is preferable to an asynchronous one.

This example shows how to make a simple synchronous request.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'ToggelProcess.action', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.send("id="+id);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```